# How to control a variable from the Django template and increment it

Tags: python, django, loops, iteration

I have a problem creating a slideshow (well more like a one way slideshow) with random sequence every time, and no repeated pictures. I do not know how to connect the "next" button with the previously made sequence and is it possible for the template to increment a python counter.

```py
def ChemistryView(request):
    all_private_keys = PostForChemistry.objects.all()
    list_of_private_keys = [post.id for post in all_private_keys]
    random_ids = random.shuffle(list_of_private_keys)
    priv = list_of_private_keys[0]
    i = 1


    querysetforchem = PostForChemistry.objects.get(pk=list_of_private_keys[0])
    context = {
        "querysetforchem" : querysetforchem,
        "list_of_private_keys" : list_of_private_keys
    }
    return render(request, 'main/chemistry.html', context)
```

I want a single id object on screen at a time and for it to increment not to the bigger one, but to the next in the random list.

Comment: Try to use object.id

Comment: @AseelAshraf i used that in the template to show the id, but i do not kniw how to use it as a variable that talks back to the backend and increments (js?)

Comment: In that case you should use javascript

Comment: @AseelAshraf may you help me how? If you want I can post my template?

Comment: Contact me on skype “aseel.ashraf”